# What happened to the percent of accepted answers?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, accept-rate

I'm sure this is a dup, but what happened to this feature?

Not too long ago, people's name had the percent of questions on which they accepted an answer. I don't remember reading that it changed in the blog or elsewhere, yet suddenly this is gone.

Comment: Update - apparently this feature [has been removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/146438)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see it on your question here.

You must either be on the site anonymously or on one of the sites that you don't have enough non-CW questions (4) asked to have a rating yet.

Comment: Or some monkey is covering it with grease.

Comment: "Well, of course we're going to fling poo at him."

Comment: I remember not being able to see it on my own questions. Is there a minimum reputation you must reach to see it?

Comment: @Justin, Not that I know of.

Comment: Thanks, it must have been I didn't have 4 questions yet.