# Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accept-rate

My feature request (or anti-feature-request perhaps) is the following:
**Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate.**

For those of you who know "Fawlty Towers", the whole issue of a visible accept rate and our behavior towards it starts to feel like ["Don't mention the war!"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xnNhzgcWTk).

We generally seem to agree that harassing a user about it is not appropriate and that our decision to answer a question should not depend on it, yet we display it in varying terrorist-threat-levels of color. Yes dear users, please don't pay any attention to the brightly orange colored percentage you see there. And whatever you do, don't bring it up.

But as long as you're displaying the accept rate, people will comment on it, criticize users for it and possibly reconsider answering because of it. And while I'm of the opinion that a low accept rate should not stop you from answering (we're here to make the internet better after all) and that the possible reputation gain (or lack thereof) should not factor in either, I can't blame users for considering it. It's in their face after all. And we're only people.

So let's take the issue off the table. Or at least partially. Information about a user's acceptance behavior can still always be gathered from the profile. But at least that would be less in-your-face.

**"But it helps me to see if a user is a help vampire!"**
I'm still wondering if those are of the sparkly variety as well, but I digress. So what? If the question is bad, downvote it. Evaluate a question on its individual value. There is no need to take a user's history into account. There might be a correlation between the quality of a question and a user's accept rate, but there doesn't have to be. And if there is, the bigger problem is the question's quality.

**"Exactly! A user with a low accept rate might indicate there's a problem!"**
I'm not arguing we should get rid of the accept-rate value within SO/SE. After all, this Q&A works based on up and downvotes, as well as the acceptance of an answer. But why not use it behind the scenes to (very occasionally) nudge the user with a statement like:

> "You have received several answers to your questions, yet have not accepted an answer as correct or helpful in a while. You might want to evaluate them and where possible [accept them as correct or helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)".

After all, in the various questions with regards to comments on low accept rates, if any comments are encouraged at all, then they are of this soft variety. So why not let the system take care of that?

I feel this would take the whole issue of accept rate off the table, while still providing the user with the information he might have missed or needs. (As a bonus, it would reduce the frequency with which the topic is brought up here on Meta) And those users who would ignore this information are most likely not convinced by a displayed percentage either.

Comment: I agree - First they added the percentage to publicly "shame" a user. The, when comments were too rude, they allowed removing them with a single flag. These are contradictory features...

Comment: @Gnoupi Exactly. And the abuse I see (though admittedly I actively look for it and correct it) is quite severe. One of the worst examples is [this one](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1067618#1067618) where a user actually made that comment an answer, which was subsequently accepted by the OP. Quickly flagged and deleted, but certainly something is wrong there. And this example is not an exception unfortunately.

Comment: @Bart: from what i see here it seems to me that users are very aware of the metrics so my question would be: how to quantify the term "help vampire users"? If there's only a couple of hundreds people that occasionally do so (on over a million of SO users i guess) then the problem is not relevant, or is it?

Comment: @Bart, in retrospect so obvious.  Off to play with data explorer I go!

Comment: @KonradRudolph It really depends on the type of badgering. If merely informing in nature, fine. But on more than one occasion (and apparently frequently enough for this request to be honored) it tended to get quite ugly. Which is also why I stated that the system should be able to handle the friendly message behind the scenes, rather than rely on users. It seems however that this second part of the request has not (yet?) been implemented. Let's see how this goes.

Comment: @Spacedman That is rather slippery-slope indeed. A visible accept rate was addressed because of practical problems/negative side-effects. If you could make a similar well-argued and evidence based argument for the other items, by all means go ahead. But I don't see similar problems for usernames, gravatars and other items.

Comment: @Spacedman: Heh, very inventive, but this argument is oft deployed and seldom meaningful. Yes, you can move the line anywhere. No, we're not going to. The suggestion is to put the line _here_, so the argument should focus on that. A proposal to hide names from questions is _something else_.

Comment: Finally. When I was arguing that this metric is awful and promotes stupid actions like marking answers as answers when they aren't, I only got people arguing with me how I should ask better questions and not give up on questions. Now finally someone was able to prove that terrible metric has to go, and It's gone. HOORAY!

Comment: Just thought I'd share an example of why I would have thought twice if there was an accept rate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848585/some-xe2-programs-dont-show-new-executable-icons-in-windows-explorer

Comment: Voted to close as no-repro because it is, this is resolved, and closing this should prevent the occasional noise answer here. If anybody wants to reinstate this for some reason, post it as a new FR.

Comment: That works too, if you'd prefer to stop comments and votes as well. Either way.

Comment: Now that user’s acceptance rate is not displayed, is there a way to calculate it?

Comment: @matt you could always see how many questions a user asked, and narrow that down to accepted ones with a search like `user:USERID is:question hasaccepted:yes`

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Starting with the next build accept rate will no longer be shown.

We're still keeping track of it on the backend for various things, but the negative behavior its display encourages outweighs its benefits.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ I wouldn't say that this would have too much effect on people - usually people who don't accept answers aren't going to accept even if you do remind them. But now, I suspect that answerers will be a little more high strung; making sure that the OP accepted an answer and the like. Good or bad? We'll see :-)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn (or Kevin or any mod) Any idea on whether or not the user will now be poked behind the scenes, by the system, to make sure they put a reasonable effort into accepting an answer? I.e. "You've received several answers, please evaluate"?

Comment: @Bart: Not that I know of.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Eh, on the other hand, I'm not interested in SO as a tool for moral judgment. If people ask a question, I'll answer if I have time and find the question interesting. What they *"deserve"* doesn't really come into it, and I'd be suspicious of anyone who withholds information on that basis.

Comment: @jalf I don’t *withhold* anything, I just don’t see why I should expend effort for somebody who clearly doesn’t.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Because the excellent help you provide might help out far more users than this single OP asking the question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph then don't. Expend effort for your own sake: is it a fun, interesting question or not? Who cares about the OP? ;)

Comment: I like this, though I'd like to know one thing: aside from the prompt a user gets after upvoting an answer, is there any in-built prompt asking users to accept more answers if they have a low accept rate?

Comment: @Bart They already were at certain points, which is why the comments were noise in the first place.

Comment: @jalf Agreed.  Like most actions on Stack Overflow, you should focus on the content, not the user.

Comment: @SethJ If that help was in the best interest of the company I work for, yes, I would help that colleague. Likewise I would answer a good question from a user who doesn't accept all that much because the community might be well-served by it (and in turn repay me handsomely).

Comment: @Manishearth [This comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate/164654#comment480310_164654) refers to my earlier comment asking the same question. That might be a bit of a missed opportunity. But let's see how things go.

Comment: @Bart, that's why I said I hesitate. If it's in the best interests of the community and I can provide the best answer, or an important insight that's been missed by others, I still answer. But if it's something I _could_ answer but don't feel particularly compelled to put in the research required, and I see that the guy has a 0% (or worse, IMO, 20% - bc someone with 0% might not know about accepting as being good practice) accept rate, I might not bother.

Comment: Choosing an answer is not analogous to a "Thank You". If the answer does not help it should not be chosen. "Thank You's" are superfluous and distracting.

Comment: (Re the above comments. (Ping @SethJ, for one.)) The SE site on which I'm most active is [judaism.se] and I confess to having a fairly low accept rate (generally hovering around 50%). This is partially because, on that site, many a question has a plurality of answers that are deserving of being accepted. (And it's partially because I was incompletely satisfied with the answers I got to some questions.) Any time I was completely satisfied with one and only one answer, I accepted it. (Just one user's data point.)

Comment: @msh210: You should still pick an answer to be accepted. If there are multiple candidates with equal weight, draw straws.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, why? Or, if you can only appeal to authority and not cite a reason, then: says who?

Comment: @msh210: Um, the FAQ, every meta question about accepting answers, precedence, the infrastructure of the site, ..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, there's no advice or policy about when to accept and when not to in [the FAQ list](http://mi.yodeya.com/faq) or the site infrastructure. If you wish to appeal to "every" meta question about accepting answers or to precedent (sic) you'll need to specify.

Comment: @msh210: The FAQ you helpfully linked us to (thanks for saving me the trouble) says: `When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.` Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, right. Implication: if you haven't so decided, then don't "draw straws".

Comment: @msh210: Do decide! The following paragraph in the FAQ explains why this is a good thing and what accepting answers means. Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28276/what-answer-to-accept

Comment: Focus on content? The information if an answer was helpful is a very important detail of the content(if it is not so, why not simply remove the option to accept an answer).  
Users which do not find it necessary to decide if their question has been answered, don't worry about the "content". Don't focus on users? Let's remove reputation, badges, custom user-names, aboutme.

Comment: @DJDavid98: That's another point: I felt obligated to accept very poor answers just to keep this number at 100%!.

Comment: For those who prefer not to answer questions of those users with low accept rates, I think one thing to consider is that you are not only punishing them, but other users who could have benefited from your answer.  If it was a good question, that means there are others, possible good members of the SO community, who have the same question, who could have benefited from your knowledge.

Comment: @Jens: Nobody needs to have 100%. Personally, if i see users with 100% and many questions i have the feeling that these people accept answers arbitrarily. So while it's desirable to keep it high because it shows that you care about the people who spend their time to help you and it also shows the high quality of your questions(since you get good response), it's not essential to have 100%. For what it's worth, i'm also strongly opposed to this change for the same reasons as Konrad Rudolph.

Comment: I'm glad the maintainers got to some kind of consensus, but at the moment I'm at a stage where I cannot really determine if the questioner is any good at what he is doing. This left me on quite a number of mindless goose chases, especially regarding long winding questions (and regarding crypto, there are many hard to follow questions). Reputation is a very bad indicator for this, accept rate was much better. Maybe you can find some other way for me to get information about the users past behavior, spitting through the users profile takes too much time.

Comment: Let's be realistic. While the focus on improving the content of the site and helping out other users regardless of the accept rate is commendable, most people take the time to answer a question because they have something to gain from it, not because of sense of altruism. This change will only cause those people to be a lot more reluctant on answering questions from new users.

Comment: [Accept-rate implementation.](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/109307)

Comment: If you're still tracking it, could we please see our own accept rates in our profiles? It might be a helpful reminder that accepting right answers is important. (That's if its not already there. I can't see it.)

Comment: @StephenKennedy This would be better as a new feature request, not as a comment on an old post. Anyway: you can find it through the API. For example, here is a [bookmarklet](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC#accept) that shows accept rate of question asker, when it's used on the question page. (E.g., on this page it shows that Bart has 97% accept rate). Of course, this does not serve the purpose of *reminding*, since one has to remember to go look for the data in the first place.

Comment: Worst decision ever.

Comment: Fast forward to 2020... Some OP's will comment, "Thanks, that's it!" But they never accept or upvote the answer. Now, people cannot quickly see the bright green check mark to instantly know there's a definite fix to the question. Acceptance rate is just a stat. The word "shame' is played out. Everything is 'shame" nowadays. It's absurd.

Answer (score 260):

Alternate request:

Show the accept-rate to the owner of the question only, and only on question user-cards. That way they get a gentle reminder that they're rewarded for ticking the box, and nobody else has to see it.

And move that public metric to their profile

---

As pointed out below by bluefeet, this would probably help contribute to the Summer of Love ;-)

Comment: I like this, but the problem (to me) is that they've left the accept rate visible to all, saying [a better solution is needed before removing it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104371/154510).  IMO the public accept rate needs to die, immediately, regardless of what else they decide to do.  No more dithering about other solutions, that should be a separate concern.  Again, just IMO :P

Comment: Yes, hence "only show it to the OP" because "that drives up the accept rate" but "don't show it to the public" because "it's not a good metric". Which part are we disagreeing on Matthew?

Comment: I don't think we're disagreeing, I just want this to be a "separate request" rather than an "alternate request".  I don't want the devs to see this feature request and dither about alternatives instead of whacking the public accept rate ASAP.  (Not that I get to determine what they or you do, but I hope you get what I mean.)

Comment: I see what you're getting at. I just see the process as "let me offer another solution instead of yours but keep the discussion inline" rather than "let me open a whole other Q and you go over there and vote on it" on account of the whole discussion thing. But I agree, **the devs should consider this a contrasting feature implementation request** from the one asked above, yes?

Comment: They can show it to mods, or mods + 20k users, without showing everyone. The 20k users are supposed to be _helping new users_ and _shaping the community properly_ anyways.

Comment: This is actually an interesting option. As long as the rate is gone from public view, I have no objection to having it visible to each user personally.

Comment: I've got no problem with this as long as the tardy users are slapped with a wet fish when their accept rate drops too low. Nobody likes the *fix your accept rate* comments, but we also don't like lazy leeches who don't do the right thing on the site.

Comment: Being the Summer of Love this definitely should be removed to decrease the level of snarkiness in the comments.

Answer (score 140):

I prefer seeing the accept rate.

Being a good SO citizen includes contributing to those who attempt to help.

Not everyone with a low accept rate is a Bad Citizen. People who pay *too* much attention to it, or don't bother investigating to see *why* the poster's accept rate might be low, also fall down.

Potential answerers who use the accept rate as a reason not to assist at *all* are also missing the point. I think the majority of consistent answerers wouldn't use that as the *sole* reason to move on to the next question. It might alter the amount of *effort* put in to an answer, and I'm not sure that's bad.

Removing it might solve *that* problem, but I'd rather encourage people to become better SO citizens over the long term, balanced against the risk that someone with a low accept rate won't come back.

*Edit; minor clarification from my comments:*

I believe allowing users to avoid playing the "SO game" diminishes what SO is--my opinion.

I use the accept rate as a cue to look at their questions; perhaps they can be improved if they're not being answered, perhaps they're OT, who knows. I use it as a way to see if a user might be struggling to use SO in the way *I* believe it's meant to be used.

Comment: So how can we balance that and keep a metric that has usefulness? Mods like having an instant glance of "this is a low-rep user who doesn't accept, and has a lot of questions, they need more guidance on how to use the network" and accept-rate is one of those metrics.

Comment: @jcolebrand I'm not sure. Maybe make it visible to higher-rep users who are (in theory!) more responsible and won't use it as a big stick?

Comment: In what situation is it appropriate to make a judgment based solely on the accept rate?  If you're supposed to go through the user's profile and evaluate them (which I disagree with as well), then how is the accept rate useful?  It's just a shortcut to treating people poorly.

Comment: I didn't say it was a sole metric of usefulness, only a guiding number to show further insight into a user's practice. Removing it from the usercard and showing it on the user profile to mods and self makes sense.

Comment: @MatthewRead I never said it was; I believe I said the opposite. I think letting users *not* play the "SO game" diminishes what SO is--*my* opinion. *I* use the accept rate as a cue to look at their questions; perhaps they can be improved if they're not being answered, perhaps they're OT, who knows. I use it as a way to see if a user might be struggling to use SO in the way *I* believe it's meant to be used.

Comment: Comparing the number of people I've seen abusing others over the accept rate to those taking it as an opportunity to help, the former wins handily.  The accept rate is a bright, colorful and in-your-face; people will make judgments based solely on it.  I don't believe the benefits are worth the costs.

Comment: @MatthewRead Define "abuse". I don't have an issue with people being reminded that SO is a collaborative effort and that askers, in addition to asking quality question, should reward those who attempt to help. Downvoting based on a low accept rate? *That's* abuse, and I don't know how you'd have evidence of that. What metrics are you using to quantify abuse, and what's your definition?

Comment: I'm not talking about system abuse, I'm referring to harassing people. It can't be quanitified any more than your answer can, and if you aren't familiar with users being harassed over this, then I honestly don't think you're qualified to answer the question.  Sorry :(.  I don't have an issue with gentle and appropriate reminders in general, either -- but that's not what generally happens.

Comment: I am not at all arguing against "the game". My suggestion for a gentile reminder behind the scenes should illustrate that. I just think there is a significant difference between such a reminder and a public notice which essentially states "Here people, look at this, he's not playing the game!!"

Comment: How did religion get in to this? ;) Meh--I don't have an issue with a combination of "gentle" and "public".

Comment: @MatthewRead (a) I don't *have* to be qualified by *your* standards to answer the question, (b) I've answered what, a thousand or two questions and have enough rep to have seen most behavior on SO *anyway*, and (c) you didn't address what you mean by "abuse", what "gentle" means, etc. *I've* rarely seen anything so out-of-line I've felt moved to comment on it-YMMV. Questioning my "qualifications", or assuming there *are* any, is a canard.

Comment: I'm not going to argue over whether it's possible for an opinion to be uninformed, and yeah, obviously that was my opinion and you're not bound by it.  I also think defining every term I use is ridiculous and I could just as easily ask you to do the same for the terms you've used, by I don't think that's productive.

Comment: "*That's solidly douche territory*" - Name calling, really?  That's what we're doing now?

Comment: @jadarnel On that aspect of his response, yes--reasonable people can disagree, but telling people they're "not qualified to answer"

Comment: Fortunately (and equally unfortunately) you're one of the few people that use the metric for it's designed purpose. The problem we're facing is nasty comments based _completely_ on that value and people that could answer questions moving on to something where an answer promises 215 instead of 200 reputation points as the ultimate prize.  I have no problem with the 'moving on' part, I do take issue with pressure to do things that might not be in the best interest of future visitors and needless work placed on moderators.

Comment: @TimPost Yeah, I recognize I'm likely in the minority :/

Comment: I agree with this one a lot. I use the accept rate, but I check their actual questions to see if they have gotten good answers to their questions before saying anything about it.

Comment: Agreed, accept rate just like badge or reputation mechanism. the subjective purpose is to guide new user (though more on questioner side) how to use and participate in the community. Personally I think it works just fine. Everybody comes from a noob, for sophisticated user, just ignore it if you don't like it, this would be more reasonable than a simple-deletion requested by sophisticated user group, which doesn't sound quite fair.

Comment: I'm with you, @DaveNewton. I can't believe this is even a question. I'm so disappointed with this decision. Someone who never (or rarely) accepts an answer is discourteous. It's not about points. It's about saying "thank you".

Comment: @TimPost, if people are being nasty, punish them. Dock points from their profiles or suspend them. But don't remove a feature that helps others know if they are providing aid to someone who really doesn't care and isn't courteous.

Comment: I'm a little late to the show here, but I'm disappointed to see the accept rate gone. I've never flamed a user for not accepting an answer, but I would use it sometimes to determine whether to try and answer a question. If it is a low complexity question that I know off the top of my head I will answer no matter the accept rate.  If it takes a higher level of time investment on my part to determine an answer I will choose to invest that time on a question that has a better chance of paying me back.

Answer (score 70):

I agree: Remove the accept rate from the user card. No user should ever see another's accept rate.

My rationale is that there are no positives to showing the accept rate, and many negatives.  I've gone into more detail below.

---

First let me address [the only real positive I've seen claimed about the accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104371/154510):

> [I]ntroducing accept rates heavily increased the amount of accepted answers in the system. Which in turn helps close loops and motivate the community.

- You can't measure motivation.  But at a user level, I've never seem anything but discouragement happening because of the accept rate display.
- It seems to me that a lot of answers get accepted prematurely and, specifically due to this feature, for no reason other than to increase the accept rate.  That basically makes the acceptance mark unhelpful and inaccurate, and certainly the fact that the number of accepts increased doesn't mean anything except that shaming people works.

Another quote from that post:

> [Accept rate] is a one-dimentional metric that does not really give me enough information about how upstanding a user is in the community. It is used frequently to bully users and leaves a horrible taste.

I fail to see how the benefit is worth the horribleness.

And it is horrible; I reject the claim some have made that having a low accept rate displayed is not a form of punishment and shaming.  To quote [a comment made on an answer to another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate/23333#comment-114793):

> Accept rate isn't to shame people, but to allow answerers to concentrate more time on those people who engage more in the site – Casebash May 10 '10 at 5:32

The **purpose** is irrelevant.  What are the ***actual effects*** of labelling someone as "not worth your time"?

1. Users make comments intended to shame those with low accept rates.
2. Users make polite comments intended to gently remind a user to accept, which may still cause the user shame.  You've probably noticed that people can get awkward when you tell them they've got food in their teeth or something.  Now imagine that everyone in the room heard you tell them (equivalent of publicly posting a comment).  It would be perfectly natural to be embarrassed in such a situation.
3. Users who notice or are told that other users refuse to spend time on their questions due to the accept rate are likely to feel rejection and/or shame and/or any number of other negative emotions.

There may be the rare case where a user is genuinely glad to be reminded if they had intended to accept an answer and forgotten.  In all other cases, the emotional effect is negative.  (You may argue that this is desired, but I am not making any claim about that yet so it's irrelevant.)

Given this negative effect, let's enumerate what it causes in turn:

1. It discourages people from asking about difficult problems that are less likely to be solved.  Stack Exchange is about expertise.  Expert questions should be encouraged.
2. It punishes people who have in fact asked expert questions that haven't yet been adequately answered.  Not only with feeling rejected or whatever, but in not getting further answers.
3. As a result of the previous two, it pushes away experts who want to do more than answer, or want to participate in a site where they and other experts *could* do more than answer.
4. It pushes away people who want to participate in a site where people are treated with respect indiscriminately.
5. It aids and encourages rep whores.  Yes, everyone is free to participate as they wish, including playing the rep game.  But we should encourage excellent and constructive behavior, not just acceptable behavior.  Encouraging people to give all the attention to the easy-rep questions doesn't make this the valuable site for real development issues that we want it to be.
6. It pushes away new users who weren't aware of the feature until they received a nasty welcome.
7. Users who see negative comments think they're acceptable.

Now yes, there are users who just come to leech solutions and don't care to accept answers that they should.  Should they be punished for having a low accept rate?  Some points:

1. [Their questions may still be useful to others if answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31617/154510).
2. It's easier to use a throwaway account each time than get engaged in the site; the punishment may be ineffective.
3. Have you *seen* how many people continually post crap without learning their lesson, even if their questions go unanswered?  Again, the punishment is ineffective.
4. You'll always have people like me who will answer a decent question if they can regardless of who asked it, why they asked it, or whether they've accepted previous answers.  **The punishment is ineffective.**
5. If the punishment's ineffective, the only point in executing it is vindictiveness.  I don't want to participate in a site that promotes vindictive behavior.
6. How can it be valid to ignore questions but invalid to ignore answers (not accept them)?  This behavior seems inherently hypocritical to me.  We don't stamp "ignores questions from low accept rate users" on user cards, why should we be stamping "low accept rate" on user cards either?  Questions require effort and have value too, not just answers.  Ignoring a question due to an external factor harms the site.

Yes, we should always encourage people to leave polite and constructive comments.  But no matter how we encourage good behavior or discourage bad behavior, these comments will always be made if the accept rate is displayed.  When it comes to the accept rate, there's a simple and effective option to reduce abuse.  **Get rid of it**.  The downsides are prominent and the upside is questionable as to its existence and entirely dubious as to its ethics.  I certainly feel that the benefits of removing it greatly outweigh the benefits we purportedly get from it.

---

Some examples of how useless the accept rate is:

- Mentioning the accept rate is considered [so unconstructive that mods will delete such comments and so prevalent that flagging them auto-deletes them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103785/154510)
- Skipping questions from users with a low accept rate [is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31616/154510)
- The rate gives no indication of *why* it is what it is:

  - ["There are occasions where accepting isn't practical"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27499/154510).
  - Some users accept answers [solely to increase their rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103777/154510)
- ["[A]ccepting answers is not required"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) (unless you want people to treat you with respect and answer your question, apparently)

Comment: +1 Absolutely excellent answer. I would almost feel bad for being there first. But hey, now each upvote will get you twice the rep. :p

Comment: Hi Matt, if we remove the accept rate because it might encourage some negative commentary, then could this not lead to other things we should get rid of because there's the possibility of negative commentary. For instance, I downvoted someone and they called me a bad name. Does this mean we should get rid of downvotes too? I realize that's kind of an extreme example... One way new users on SO learn about SO is through commenting, and this includes how to accept answers. My concern is that legitimate accepts could drop as well as a result of user ignorance as to how the system works.

Comment: @jmort well, we had talked about replacing the "accept rate" with a more generalized "citizenship metric" which included other important stuff like how often they vote, whether they answer questions as well as ask, post on meta ever, etc etc etc. Not sure when/if that'll ever get done under the new regime, but it needs to happen. The problem is not the number, but that the number is a bit too narrow at the moment.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Would this metric still be publicly visible? A broader metric might certainly cut down on the targeted single-value-only comments we experience now. But should even such a metric be publicly visible?

Comment: @bart sure why not? I think at a glance knowing if someone is a reasonably responsible citizen of a particular society is kind of a useful thing.

Comment: @JeffAtwood - How would you propose keeping the accept rate from dropping as a result? I realize many SO users can be a little overzealous in their dealings with users with low accept rates. But it *is* a reminder to many that they need to go back and finish what they started by asking the question.

Comment: @JeffAtwood What doesn't click with me though is the desired effect of it. Say we have a broader metric visible to others. What should I do, or how should my behavior change if I stumble upon someone who is not acting responsibly. Other than the edits I already make or the guidance I already attempt to provide based on the actual content (the question) I see.

Comment: @JeffAtwood - This also seems a bit counter-intuitive with the goals of visibility. Almost every user action is visible. This was evident during the elections where several nominees were "outed" for having rude comments or displaying undesirable behaviors. A "citizenship metric" doesn't tell us as a community specifically how we can help the user specifically improve his/her citizenship metric and the behaviors that caused it to be low.

Comment: @jmort253 Commenting with a downvote an "exposing" yourself is optional; displaying the accept rate is not. They're not comparable.  If they were, I would point out that downvoting is massively useful, and the accept rate not.  My argument is that the costs are not worth it, not that we should remove everything that has a potential cost.

Comment: @MatthewRead - If we did eliminate the accept rate, do you think it would be acceptable for SE to display more information and notifications to the users to "teach" them how to accept answers, since the community wouldn't be doing this job anymore? The cost of eliminating accept rate is that a googler may encounter more questions with no clear indication of what solved the op's problem.

Comment: @jmort253 Certainly.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but the idea of a "citizenship metric" and determining a numerical value for identifying a good user just rubs me the wrong way. I can understand how it may be necessary or useful, but it just leaves me with a bad feeling in my mouth.

Comment: @Yawus I do not believe it's possible to do so in a useful way.  Multidimensional subjective qualities cannot be collapsed to a one-dimensional objective quantity.

Comment: @Matthew Read I was thinking about some sort of a [radar chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) with different user metrics on each axis, such as accept rate and voting, but I'm not sure if such a graphic would really help and not just be noise.

Comment: Excellent answer. One note: reputation itself is a sufficient gauge for telling "good" and "not-that-good" citizens apart. Before answering, one could check the asker's rep and decide for herself whether to answer or not.

Comment: @bytebuster I disagree that you can tell the quality of an asker by rep alone. We have a couple of habitually problematic users on our tags that are a never-ending source of frustration. Yet they have managed to amass significant rep that literally betrays the type of user they are, and in a lot of cases, the experience you'll have if you get involved with their question. I know to stay away from them by name only, not by reputation or accept rate.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: If these users are cheating on their reputation, it's an issue of preventing reputation fraud. On the other hand, everyone is free to use the site as they wish, within the confines of fair use.

Finally, the whole discussion is about 5 points of rep (accepted answer vs. upvote). **No big deal** if the asker failed to accept the answer. Others will mark it useful, providing twice as much per upvote.

Comment: @bytebuster I never said they were cheating. Being a bad user doesn't necessarily mean gaming the system.

Answer (score 63):

Before reading this I had no idea what "acceptance rate" meant - I had assumed that Stack Overflow was telling me how many of my answers had been accepted by others; I had no idea it meant how many questions I had accepted answers to.

So when someone asked "Why the low acceptance rate" on one of my questions I had no idea what they were talking about. If they had not done so I would still be in the dark.

But there is a really simply solution!

When someone starts to ask a new question, if their acceptance rate is below X% have the website show a red warning message above the Title input which states:

> Warning: You have accepted answers to only Y% of your questions, this may deter people from offering answers.

**[image: Mock up]**

Comment: My wording would be different. But still I largely agree (which most likely will not surprise you ;) )

Comment: I had no idea what you meant when you chastised me, Bart, but I am glad you did it :)

Comment: When I chastised you? What did I do? :D

Comment: What I really like about this answer is that it takes the issue offline and gives a gentle nudge to the asker automatically.  I'd also like to see notices added to the asker's inbox when the rate gets low enough.

Comment: This is the wrong place to put a reminder like this.  When someone has a question, you're trying to take them _off track of what they were doing_ (and asking them to do another kind of activity) by this kind of reminder in this specific location.

Comment: I disagree, you should remind them in places they go to perform frequent tasks such as asking questions / answering questions, etc

Comment: So does this keep the public acceptance rate display around or get rid of it?

Answer (score 44):

I have always found the accept rate display to be stupid, useless and prone to causing noise and fighting instead of promoting better questions and answers.

There are people who go around following people with low accept rates and commenting things like "Go accept answers or I won't answer your question" and other garbage.

Comment: Exactly. And when I see users come to Meta with a statement like "I have accepted some answers because I felt pressured", I feel there is something wrong.

Comment: Some people have no life

Comment: And then there are people that see who made a meta post and downvote it because of that. Savages. I have my own crew of haters, but not nearly as many as you have accrued. Also, good to see you around again, been keeping quiet or oppressed?

Comment: I know I personally have answered questions where I have seen people respond in the same/similar way. And in some cases be the first and only one to respond.

Comment: I'm going to start making noise about this after the holidays. We seem to have arrived at a consensus, so we really need an official answer on if it is, or is not going away. I feel that displaying it is a tacit endorsement of the problematic behavior it creates, and I really hope we get rid of it soon. We should be encouraging people to find questions to answer based on their knowledge and abilities, not the probability of an acceptance bonus.

Answer (score 36):

The accept rate is a *proxy* for a person's ability to ask good questions and encourage good answers. With a large enough statistical sample, I think it's a valid proxy. If someone asks 100 questions, and accepts only 5 answers, the odds are that there's a problem.

People providing answers on Stack Overflow are *volunteers*. I don't get paid for it, and neither do most of you. (Yes, yes...SO has employees. Don't get sidetracked.) A volunteer's time is a valuable and limited commodity, and anything that ignores this basic premise is doomed to failure from a psychological standpoint.

There's certainly a valid case to be made that small samples lead to skewed results. If you're a new user with only 2 questions and 1 accepted, that leaves you with a 50% accept rate. Perhaps a red/green metric with a minimum threshold of asked/unanswered questions before it can go red is a better option than a displayed percentage.

In the end, though, people will apply a metric whether you provide them one or not. Whether it's accept rate, overall reputation, or upvotes/downvotes on a question, many people *will* anchor their evaluations on *something* before determining whether to read a question in-depth. You won't be able to remove this basic instinct; at best, you will shift it to some other discriminator.

I'll upvote any sensible suggestion for improving a proxy metric, but I simply can't agree with anything that ignores basic sociology or psychology. Removing the accept rate just moves the cheese; it doesn't get you out of the trap.

Comment: The accept rate is a bad, [one-dimensional](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104371/154510) proxy and I don't see any evidence whatsoever that it's a net positive, and even if so, whether the costs are worth it.  (Some of the costs being qualitative, of course.)

Comment: Regarding your third paragraph, accept rate is not calculated until the user has four or more qualifying questions: questions more than three days old, which have an answer posted.

Comment: @matt see my comment on Kevin's accepted answer here

Comment: "people will anchor their evaluations on something before determining whether to read a question in-depth" - Precisely.

Answer (score 23):

I [was going to propose this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135275/reduce-or-eliminate-accepted-answer-bonus/135276#comment377112_135276), then I ran out of time, so I'm glad to see it's been proposed and generally welcomed. In the context of an otherwise fine question, a comment such as this:

> You really need to work on your accept rate. Go accept some answers on your other questions if you want an answer for this one

... is little more than a stain. Additionally, 'accept rate proding' (aka bullying, aka nagging) is one of the largest sources of comment flags we receive. They are either just noise, or *obsolete* noise when the person does as asked. Sometimes, people accept answers that didn't *really* help them just to try to comply. That's unfortunate. Displaying it,at least in my opinion seems like a tacit endorsement of the problematic behavior it encourages. That's also unfortunate.

I would like to see the actual calculated metric vanish almost entirely. People can still take a glance at your profile and see how many questions you've accepted answers on, but doing so would probably take more effort than just answering the current question to begin with. I don't see anything wrong with showing it to the question author *only* if it's consistently low.

Anyway, as Bill dropped a 100 rep bounty on this, I'm going to chime in and say that moderators would not be at all displeased if that metric went away.

Comment: You could make a [black cloud](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138119/if-you-really-want-to-reduce-the-snark-level/138184#138184) about it

Comment: @bobobobo You _really_ think that programmers need more 'clouds'? Seriously? What is that I don't even.

Comment: It's just a suggestion to say, you know, if you're going to go as far as to get mad at a user for not strictly obeying site rules, you may as well draw a black cloud on his screen

Answer (score 12):

About the only context in which the accept rate is marginally useful is when it is at `0%`: in the overwhelming majority of cases it tells you that the poster is not aware of the purpose of the check mark outline next to the answers, and may benefit from a brief explanation. Once the user accepts an answer for the first time, mentioning the accept rate is almost certainly counterproductive.

However, the absence of the "Scholar" badge already tells you that the user does not know how to accept answers, so displaying the accept rate is redundant.

Moreover, the process of making the user aware of the "accept" feature could be automated with a gentle reminder to consider accepting an answer, if this is the behavior the sites would like to promote. A very gentle reminder can be sent only once to users without the "Scholar" badge, and only if they have at least one answer with the score of at least two that has not been accepted for three or more days.

Comment: The reminder seems to be already there, since the first question I posted on Stack (never done before, I am more a SharePoint Overflow user) was greeted with a nice "Remember you can mark this answer" when I upvoted the just posted answer before marking it (upvote first if it seems usefull, check if it resolve the problem and *then* mark). Are you implying displaying it every time untill the user start to accept answers? I would say... go for it.

Answer (score 12):

I think accept rate shouldn't have anything to do with whether a user answers a question or not.  You're talking about 15 reputation, while upvotes from a **good** question can easily exceed that.

So since it shouldn't have an effect on whether a user answers a question or not, **why not just take it away then?**  What's the point in having a statistic in front of the user that says ***hey, don't answer this, move on***?  I don't think it's a good idea to put a sign post on otherwise good questions that says **don't bother**.

[image]

So, if you have to display accept rate, just put it in a user's profile screen, where you have to do quite a bit of click through to find this number out.

[image]

Should this be public information?  Arguments go for and against.  If it is public information, then only people who *really* care about accept rate can find this information at a glance, instead of having to really troll through the user's previous posts to find the answer to this question.

Comment: I meant, since it's useless, it should be removed

Comment: I agree. My comment was not meant to invalidate your answer. I think however that we should not merely move it to another place, but make it completely publicly invisible. Perhaps visible to the user only.

Comment: It's not about points. It's about saying "thank you".

Answer (score 9):

Stack Exchange is a feedback loop and there is a difference of opinion as to the entry point. The varying communities would be a fascinating study in group dynamics.

The topic at hand:

There is one theory that views the charity of the says that if we're nice, we'll attract more quality answerers and we'll perpetually be an ever-growing group of experts motivated by simply helping a peer in need. In this theory, acceptance rate is perceived as ammunition to attack a user and should be removed.

There is an alternate theory that views the shared community values as the entry point. This one says that the extant experts are all too often left unrewarded for their volunteer efforts. In this theory, "work on acceptance rate" as an example of coaching a user on how to be a "productive" member of a community. If you want to be a member of the community, there is an initial grace period, but eventually you need to accept and espouse the community's values.

I lean slightly toward the latter, honestly. I am not an expert. I am not a power user. I am here to learn and I understand that the folks here are not indebted to me to answer my question. As such, I wear my acceptance rate with pride because *it shows how much I value this community*. That is how I understand Acceptance Rate. It is a metric that demonstrates the community's value to me.

Comment: @Bart Agreed. That's the mod's job ... to pull the badgers into a room and remind of the ethic/value.

Comment: They are busy enough however. Take visible accept-rate off the table (don't destroy it. Let the system keep it behind the scenes and handle it) and you'll have less noise to deal with. Surely there will be those who might look at the OP's history and still comment accordingly, but the number will be (I think significantly) lower.

Comment: As I said. I can only argue from my perspective as one of the Gammas. I am proud of my accept rate because I believe it shows that I am truly invested in the community and willing to demonstrate how much I value the community. Other perspectives may vary.

Comment: That's fair enough. And I'm sure you're an excellent user with appropriate behavior. But the number of accept-rate-badgers (I like that word actually) I flag into oblivion in the time I spend on this site is significant enough not to ignore and outweighs the upside of a visible accept-rate IMHO.

Comment: @swasheck, I am fine with your point: it would seem that the system can help if it make people value the answer we all give. But the point is that if you are more inclined to answer question than asking, you may find yourself with a very low score when your few questions don't find a real answer. As you say, I like to pay back the effor, so I upvote helpfull info even if they don't fix my problem or answer my question. But as it is now the system is forcing me to accept those answer (or hope no one upvotes them).

Comment: @swasheck also please see my answer somewhere on this question. I hope my point is clear, and I am really interested in knowing what you think about it - you seem to be more oriented to the "score should be looked at" point of view, so I would like to hear your opinion on the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Further to the answer by jcolebrand :

> Show the accept-rate to the owner of the question only, and only on
>   question user-cards. That way they get a gentle reminder that they're
>   rewarded for ticking the box, and nobody else has to see it.
>
> And move that public metric to their profile

An automated peroidic prompt when the answer accept rate falls below a given threshold.

Answer (score 8):

I think it is a good motivation for users to reward and identify correctness in answers, but would prefer to instead see:

'8 unaccepted questions' as opposed to '74% acceptance rate'

this would inherently remind users they have a finite number of questions they can go back and review to accept/bounty, and may encourage others to view those 8 questions (assuming that number is a link, which I believe it should  be regardless of the phrasing)

so rather than a percent which I view as a grade (out of 100%) , it should have more of an informative todo list for the user.

74% unaccepted doesn't mean much if you've only asked 4 questions (other than incorrect math)

100 unaccepted questions is a lot even if you've asked 1000 questions here...

I hope this makes sense to someone else!

Comment: That is all fine and well, but then just show it to the user. Make them aware of it. Why show it to anyone else? There is no need for that and it leads to all sorts of trouble. I don't have any problem with any metric being shown to the users themselves.

Comment: @Bart but I feel like not showing it publicly can allow a user to never accept any questions, and that seems counter-productive to me. Publicly showing the stats - sure it can be embarrasing - but it is sort of a necessary evil. People should accept their answers if they were given correct advise (IMO)

Comment: I completely agree with that. I don't think anyone should badger someone based on their acceptance rate, unless they see the user had thanked them for the correct answer. I see what you mean about how it leads to *bullying* for acceptance, but at the same time I think it leads to more good than bad. It is important to follow up on questions that you asked when other people took time to help you. Plus, it helps others quickly see what the correct answer is. To your point, I do usually just look for the highest # of votes even if it is not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is the actual accept rate, not the *display* of the accept rate. If people asking questions cared enough and were courteous to their fellow users, they would accept answers.  It's not about points.  It's about saying "thank you".

Comment: @Bart, there are ways to punish people who abuse the system. Don't break the system because of them.

Comment: I don't think this decision will break the system at all. It will be just fine.

Comment: I sort of agree with you...just not that the green check mark is a Thank You.

Comment: @sixlettervariables, to be clear, _I_ don't need the checkmark. I just need to see that _someone_ is going to get a checkmark for their effort to help the asker.

Comment: @SethJ: if and only if there is a correct answer present, right?

Answer (score 5):

I have had a similar discussion recently on the meta site for the SharePoint Stack Exchange site: [Acceptance Rate And Unanswered questions](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/740/acceptance-rate-and-unanswered-questions).

To resume my post, I was wondering what I should do with some of my old, unanswered questions. I have very few question (about five) so each one has a big impact on the total score. Yet, I still don't feel that I should be "forced" to accept an answer and give the impression a question is "resolved" only because the score felt to 25%.

Have a look at this question for example (yes, it is the same reference I gived on the other meta): [Purpose of the <MAPPINGS> CAML element in a custom Choice Field definition](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21349/purpose-of-the-mappings-caml-element-in-a-custom-choice-field-definition). Valid, could be answerable, but yet... no one really knows or can give a solid evidence that the feature was dropped/don't work. I may even say that my question contanins more in-deepth information than the answer, and the information I found are pointing opposite directions.

Now, for a similar question I have the following choices:

- Start a bounty, and probably lose it. It is pretty evident no one know this (except *maybe* Microsoft, and I'm not so sure...)
- Delete the question because "it is not answerable" with our knowledge. This would mean destroy all the info that it may contain.
- Chose the most voted answer as an aswer, even if it doesn't resolve the problem. I am fine with up-voting useful answer that can help other even if they don't actually answer the question, I am *not so fine* in marking them as answer while they didn't fix the problem.
- Create a placeholder answer (like I did) to tell others what I have done for now, and then edit/delete it if something better is posted.

As you may see, I have gone for the last option. But this only gives the impression that that question is resolved, which in truth isn't.

I see at least two basic errors in the current system:

- We are inclined to upvote **useful** answer. This means that if the answer is not a complete solution, but shows effort and helps, we will upvote it. This in turn make it a candidate answer for the accept rate calc script. Trad: I must not vote an answer that I won't accept, and hope that others don't do that too... Pretty lame, isn't it?
- The score doesn't matter. No, it doesn't, but let's display it red, will ya? Please don't look at that 0%, but let's display it, OK? See it? Please ignore me... Sounds like Glados. The point is: if we see that score, we will make consideration on it. If we see that the poster never upvote an accept *valid* answer we will skip it. It is lame, but it is real.

So now what can we do? Let's think about it. The system should be there to *remember* people to accept answer, but as now is used by people to decide if they should ignore a question. So we need a way to still remember people they should accept **valid** answer, but at the same time make it less invasive, so that other people won't get distracted by it.

I belive that hidding it from the question can be a good start, as other suggested. I would actually go further. Make the score more visible based on the ammount of unmarked questions? That is, we have only two options there: if the score should be ignored, then please remove it - **forever** - and never talk about it again - give the user some message, some prompt but remove the score from the question. If otherwise it should be looked at, then make it more visible the more the user seems to ignore upvoting/marking. An user with four questions (and 9999 answers)  and 2 of it unmarked is not the same of an user with 0 answer, 9999 question and 5000 of it unmarked.

(I noticed this question only now, and I hope this won't be seen as necroposting, but I felt I needed to add my point of view.)

Answer (score 5):

The real, root problem is that the ratio of points granted for accepted vs. upvoted does not correspond to the value we place on them as a community.

The questions and answers belong to the community, over time, in a very real sense. And, the community votes - from disinterested third parties - are more meaningful than *one* vote from the questioner. Since having been chosen as the correct answer already imparts psychological karma, an accepted action should grant *fewer* votes to the answerer than an upvote.

Removing the visible accept rate hides the user's behavior and makes the community more anonymous. These are the exact kinds of community attributes that result in the worst behavior. E.g., driving in traffic; commenting on the Internet in general. Anonymity and lack of accountability foster bad behavior every time. Public knowledge is a *positive* social force that keeps societies friendly. Witness the anonymity of large cities, lack of public / social repercussions for bad behavior and the results vs. small towns with cohesive social networks.

Comment: Since the feature was removed from the Stack Exchange infrastructure about a year ago, I'm left wondering what value you thought your answer would give. It isn't my down-vote, but I confess to being sorely tempted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler he's objecting to the decision, looks like a legit answer. Personally I don't agree with it, but still valid answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to answer this:

What is the steady state of displaying accept rate, but discouraging anyone else from commenting on it?

The steady state is this:  New users with a low accept rate will probably fail to get as many good answers to their questions as people with higher accept rates, but won't really know why (because no one is telling them).

Which points bask to the question.  Just get rid of the accept rate if it's considered bad form to say anything about it, or even take it into consideration as to whether or not to answer a question.

Answer (score 2):

We have been through this before. [The](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/unanswered-questions-and-accept-rate) [site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40735/poor-answers-and-accept-rate) [owners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101741/accept-rate-suggestion) [need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37551/accept-rate-usefulness) to make a policy because otherwise, [we are going to keep flip-flopping between showing it and not showing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11).

The problem is no one is going to be happy whichever way this goes AGAIN.

Do a search on META and you'll find hundreds of discussions on the Accept Rate.

Comment: Is the last link you point to what you intended to point to? And I'm well aware of the significant amount of discussions on accept rate.

Answer (score -2):

Just a bit of a personal perspective - this is meta, after all.

Funny how the word "meritocracy" has taken on a bad connotation in certain contexts in today's world.  At first superficial glance, one would swear that that's *exactly* what SE is, and what it was always intended to be - a meritocracy with top respondents gaining a reputation *par excellence*. And rightly so, given the value they add to the state of globally-available knowledge. Productivity and quality communities come first, and thereby, individuals benefit most.  Those who spend considerable time putting quality knowledge into SE deserve fair rewards, to encourage them to continue to act, possibly producing more masters (programmers/writers/mathematicians/what have you). "The needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few." So support those who ultimately help the uncounted many.

Sadly, what's good for the goose apparently *isn't* good for the gander. It is more than acceptable, encouraged in fact, for top respondents to put their time (often considerable amounts of it) into answering questions, but to expect the simple courtesy of a single vote or an accept is apparently somehow absurd because this creates an atmosphere of mutual monitoring. When in society have we ever not monitored others? Respondents are supposed to be altruistic, expecting nothing in return.

FWIW I'm no. 12 on gamedev.SE for the moment, and the number of answers I've given that have received zero attention, even in cases where there *are no other answers*, is considerable. The same goes for many other top users there, at least those who don't observe the user carefully before answering (you see, perhaps it is I who is the charitable fool that likes to help the brand new users...and I who pays the price for it). This has increased noticeably since the accept rate vanished from easy public view. I've begun to feel that the typical user has the attention span of an orange. I mention my rank only because it implies I'm no idiot as far as the sites have a few thousand points on. I get 0 or if I'm lucky, 1 vote, and those are most often never accepted. Rarely, we hit the jackpot with unremarkable answers and get tons of votes; the imbalance here is utterly disproportionate. I have to *explicitly ask*, months or years after the fact, for the checkmark on such answers, provided no one else received it or I got the most votes (often just marginally). About 1 in 6 such users then responds apologetically and with thanks. That's rare, regardless of the assistance provided.

What's more, I find it exceptionally odd that I have been able, with no extraordinary effort, to maintain a 92% accept rate on SO and a 95% accept rate on gamedev, for much of my SE career. It's just... common courtesy. Maybe you're not always thrilled with the answers you get, but after some time - several weeks, months or even years - hell, just deliver a reward to those most helpful to you.

In conclusion: Lack of a visible accept rate is gradually making me more and more jaded and less willing to help new and/or low acceptance users, *in nearly every instance*. I feel making this change was regrettable indeed, an overly simplistic, knee-jerk reaction to a complex and worsening problem. This affects the output of users who would otherwise add considerable value to the SE experience.

**The game, so to speak, is broken.**

No one can force votes, but public pressure to conform is part of human society, for better or for worse. The general public can and should demand decent and polite behaviour that acknowledges the positive actions of others - i.e. that askers place the checkmark when it is deemed appropriate to do so. While I don't condone abusive remarks, we certainly should bring back the accept rate at least as visible to higher-ranked, trusted users (say at the 5000 points mark) who otherwise use the system with care and respect. This also encourages the starting run which for so many has a snowball effect in bringing them back to the site - good, steady rewards elicit good, steady engagement.

**P.S.** Perhaps some will say I'm complaining unnecessarily; I'm really not and am very fortunate to have gained the rep I have on gamedev specifically. But given this state of affairs, I will henceforth be far more frugal with the questions I actually choose to answer, as it clear that the average SE user is not being encouraged sufficiently to thank those who spend their time responding.

Comment: Why in the world are you soapboxing on a feature-request that was implemented years ago? Accept rate is dead and gone, and won't be coming back.

Comment: @ale Why in the world are you asking me that question? Because many, including Jeff Atwood, weren't entirely happy with the decision and the changes it entailed. But by the borderline-insulting tone of your comment, I can see which side you have taken. Also, I don't believe SE has ever had a policy of censoring answers based on the time they've been open for. That is the reason these threads stay open permanently.

Comment: I really think you don't. I'm not in favor of bringing up long-dead conversations to no end, though.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer If you want the accept rate display reinstated, make a good case for it and post it as a new FR.

Comment: You have made no claim to support your statement that the accept rate would rectify your current situation. The loss in the first place may have coincided with fewer votes being cast your way, but there's no proof that this is just a coincidence. There could be numerous reasons why there was a drop in favourable voting towards you when the accept rate disappeared. Interesting to note: [your voting behaviour](//gamedev.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) has also been lacking. With ~40K questions and ~60K answers (~100K posts), you've voted *less than* 2K times (< 2%) in 6 years.